# Showing a hidden div with JQuery (not able to show full height)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a hidden div that I'm trying to show after a user submits a form... but when I try to show it I can only get it to show a 10px height

```
<div class="yuzo_related_post style-1">
</div>

      jQuery('.hidden-blog').slideDown();
      jQuery('#readmore').hide();
     jQuery('.fancybox-wrap').hide();
     jQuery('.fancybox-overlay').hide();
     jQuery('.yuzo_related_post').show();
```

Try going to [this](http://bit.ly/1O7traw) page and running the above jQuery in the console to see what I mean.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `<div class="relatedThumb">` are styled with `height: 10px;` by I don't who (inline styling).

One way to fix it is to put

```
jQuery('.yuzo_wraps .relatedthumb').css("height", "100%");
```

Comment: Nice, I think that's in the native code for the plugin. thanks